# create a new text field when click on previous text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a new text field while clicking on an already created text field.
I have written the function which is working but the problem is, it should only create a new text field when clicking on the last one, for example if there are three text fields and clicking on first two will not add a new text field. Only the clicking on third text field can create a new. with the following code it is not working properly (its a Java script function):

```
    var FieldCount=1;
    function addInputField(count)  //on add input button click
    {           

        alert(FieldCount);
        alert(count);
         if(FieldCount == count) 
        {

            FieldCount++; 


            var field = "#textfield_"+count;

            $node = '<input id="textfield_'+FieldCount+'" type="text" name="textfield"    onClick="addInputField(FieldCount);" />';
            $(field).after($node);

        }

    };
```

There is just one text field in the begging when page loads that is:

```
    <input id="textfield_1" type="text" name="textfield" onClick="addInputField(FieldCount);" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to unbind the click event for the textbox after is has been clicked.

**HTML:**

```
<input id="textfield_1" type="text" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#textfield_1").click(function () {
        addInputField(FieldCount);
    });
});

var FieldCount = 1;

function addInputField(count) //on add input button click
{

    //alert(FieldCount);
    //alert(count);
    if (FieldCount == count) //max input box allowed
    {

        FieldCount++; //text box added increment
        //add input box

        var field = "#textfield_" + count;


        $node = '<input id="textfield_' + FieldCount + '" type="text" name="textfield" />';
        $(field).unbind("click").after($node);

        $('#textfield_' + FieldCount).click(function () {
            addInputField(FieldCount);
        });

        //text box increment
    }

};
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/bz5q4/

You could also use `focus` instead of `click` to ensure that if the user tabs into the field another one is created.

Comment: Unbinding click may not be suited if you have other methods listening to the click event.

Comment: what about using 3 lines of code instead of 2312321321? http://jsfiddle.net/APnHy/3/

Comment: I tried this code and its working like a charm.. :) thanks a bundle

Answer (score 2):

get rid of that inline crap and do something sexier

```
$('form').on('click', 'input:last', function() {
   $(this).after( $(this).clone() );
})
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/APnHy/3/

Answer (score 2):

Don't need to bind and unbind Try this:-

Create element in a more readable way using jquery element constructor. Use Event delegation to the last input element created ever.

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wF9vX/)

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[type=text]:last' ,create);

function create(e)
{
  var input = $('<input />',{
        id: "textfield_" + ($(this).index() + 1),
        type:"text",
        name:"textfield"
    });
    
    $(this).after(input);
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version that attaches the behavior to a class and stores the index in the element, which makes it nicely robust:

**HTML:**

```
<input class="incfield" type="text" name="textfield" data-index="1" />
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    var createNewField = function(){
        var index = $(this).data('index');
        if (index == $('input.incfield').length) {
            var $node = $('<input class="incfield" name="textfield" />');
            $node.data('index', index + 1);
            $node.click(createNewField);
            $(this).after($node);
        }
    };
    $('input.incfield').on('click', createNewField);
});
```

[Here it is the obligatory jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HKXq4/)

**UPDATE:** Much cleaner version, using [jQuery.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) -- eliminates the need for storing data. Thanks David Fregoli for pointing out the alternative.

**HTML:**

```
<input class="incfield" type="text" name="textfield" />
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    var createNewField = function(){
        var $node = $('<input class="incfield" type="text" name="textfield" />');
        $node.one('click', createNewField);
        $(this).after($node);
    };
    $('input.incfield').one('click', createNewField);
});
```

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HKXq4/2/)

Comment: You can avoid some code using `one` instead of `on` for binding one-off events

Comment: @DavidFregoli oh, that's very cool, thank you! I'll update with a better version. :)